# Error Message ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I run the following program and received an error message from line "data = data.values.astype(float)" which in turn from "data = read_stock('snp500.csv')"

```
 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd
 import math
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 %matplotlib inline

 def read_stock(filename, normalize=True):
     data = pd.read_csv(filename)                                     #pd.read_csv
     data = data.iloc[:, 1:6]                                        #iloc[:,1:6]  
     data = data.values.astype(float)
     data = pd.DataFrame(data)
     if normalize:
         data = data.apply(lambda x: (x - np.mean(x)) / (np.max(x) - np.min(x)))
         return data

 data1 = pd.read_csv('snp500.csv')
 print(data1.head())

 data = read_stock('snp500.csv')
 print(data[:3])                                                       #data[:3])

 plt.title('SP500 Index')
 plt.plot(data)                                                        #plot normalized S&P 500 index'
 plt.show()
```

Here is a sample from snp500.csv:
[snp500.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83vRF.png)

I received the following error:
#ValueError:
could not convert string to float: '-'

Please advise how to resolve this error.

Comment: What's unclear? One of the values you wanted to convert into a float is the string `-` which cannot be converted to a number.

Comment: The csv file had already been revised and the problem is now fixed.